# Spring-data-jdbc - How to set schema in many-to-many relationship

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jdbc

I am following the spring.io blog here: `https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/24/spring-data-jdbc-references-and-aggregates` and have a sample SpringBoot app with Book and Author entities here: https://github.com/b-sridhar/spring-data-jdbc-example.

I get the following error: `No value supplied for the SQL parameter 'demobook': No value registered for key 'demobook'`

And while debugging noticed the SQL query that is executed is: `INSERT INTO demo.book_author (author, demo.book) VALUES (:author, :demobook)` which should have been `INSERT INTO demo.book_author (author, book) VALUES (:author, :book)`. This happens because I have the `@Table("demo.book")` as the annotation for the `Book` entity. If I remove the `demo` schema in the table name then the tests in `BookAndAuthorsTests` go through fine.

How to set the `schema` for the table `Book`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the 1.0.x release. It is fixed for 1.1.

If you upgrade your `spring-boot-starter-parent` to `2.2.0.M5` you'll get the `spring-data-jdbc` version `1.1.0.RC2` which contains the fix.

With that fix table names in `@Table` annotations do work as well as the approach of having the `NamingStrategy` return a schema.

Note: that your configuration then needs to extend `AbstractJdbcConfiguration` instead of `JdbcConfiguration`.

Another note: Your example project then chokes because the `AuthorRef` needs an explicit mapping to the table `BOOK_AUTHOR`. 
I'll leave a PR in a second.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I tried setting the `schema` using the `NamingStrategy` and the behaviour is still the same. I see in debug that the insert query is still the same i.e the column `book` is referred as `demo.book` for the `book_author` table. I can push the changes to my github example if you want.

Comment: thanks again. I have pushed the changes here: https://github.com/b-sridhar/spring-data-jdbc-example. You need to run the `SpringDataJdbcExampleApplication`. You should notice the `@Table` annotation is no longer used for the Entities.                                                               
However, the sql queries do prefix the Schema `demo` in all the queries.  The sql query for the `book_author` insert is still `INSERT INTO demo.book_author (author, demo.book) VALUES (:author, :demobook)`.

Comment: This is a bug. I created an issue for it which you might want to watch: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-421

Comment: Updates the answer, also created a PR.